# Subtract values in between Dictionaries in a RDD on PySpark

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have created and RDD where every element is a dictionary.

```
rdd.take(2)

[{'actor': 'brad',
  'good': 1,
  'bad': 0,
  'average': 0,}
 {'actor': 'tom',
  'good': 0,
  'bad': 1,
  'average': 1,}]
```

I am trying to perform arithmetic operations on the data, That is 
'actor': 'brad' and 'actor': 'tom', I want to subtract the other values having the same key and then find the final sum

That is:

```
(1-0)+(0-1)+(0-1)= -1
```

Since this is in RDD form what I tried to do is:

```
d1=rdd.filter(lambda x: x['name']=='brad').first()

 {'actor': 'brad',
  'good': 1,
  'bad': 0,
  'average': 0,}

 d2=rdd.filter(lambda x: x['name']=='tom').first()

 {'actor': 'tom',
  'good': 0,
  'bad': 1,
  'average': 1,}
```

This gives me the dictionary with the value 'brad' and 'tom'. How do I proceed with the arithmetic operation?

I tried doing this by :

```
d3 = {key: d1] - d2.get(key, 0) for key in d1.keys()}
```

But this is giving me errors.

Is there a better way to do this my manipulating the dictionaries in the RDD itself rather than breaking it down to the basic dictionary?

Thank you

Comment: `sum((d1[k] - d2[k]) for k in d1.keys() if k in ['good','bad','average'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your errors are due to wrong keys being used (`"name"` is not in the dictionary). But beside that, collecting the plain dictionary is probably the most appropriate way to do this (see note at bottom).

```
d1=rdd.filter(lambda x: x['actor']=='brad').first()
d2=rdd.filter(lambda x: x['actor']=='tom').first()
```

With a list of predefined keys:

```
keys = ['good', 'bad', 'average']
```

You can make the resulting dictionary using comprehension:

```
{key: d1[key] - d2[key] for key in keys}
# outputs:
{'average': -1, 'bad': -1, 'good': 1}
```

The sum can then be simply calculated over all dictionary values:

```
print(sum([v for v in dc.values()])) #-1
```

You can even do this over multiple dictionaries if they're collected in parallel lists (assuming you know exactly that the 2 RDDs are collected in orders allowing index by index operation)

```
[{key: d1[key] - d2[key] for key in keys}\
  for d1,d2 in zip(dicRdd1.collect(), dicRdd2.collect())]
```

You can test this logic using (your example dictionaries):

```
[{key: d1[key] - d2[key] for key in keys}\
  for d1,d2 in zip([d1], [d2])]
```

**Note:** You should avoid performing subtraction in Spark's distributed reduce operations. This is simply because subtraction is not commutative and that would cause unpredictable results.